# HTMLUNIT with Headless Selenium

Tags: selenium, htmlunit, headless

I am trying to scrape a website that contains images using a headless Selenium. 
Initially, the website populates 50 images.  If you scroll down more and more images are loaded.

Windows 7 x64
python 2.7
recent install of selenium

[1] Non-Headless
Navigating to the website with selenium as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(url)
browser.execute_script('window.scrollBy(0, 10000)')
browser.page_source
```

This works (if anyone has a better suggestion please let me know).
I can continue to *scrollBy()* until I reach the end and then pull the source page.

[2] Headless with HTMLUNIT

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Remote(desired_capabilities=webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.HTMLUNIT)
driver.get(url)
```

I cannot use *scrollBy()* in this headless environment.
Any suggestions on how to scrape this kind of page?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One option is to study the JavaScript to see how it calculates what to load next. Then implement that logic in your scraping client instead. Once you have done that, you can use faster scraping tools like Perl's WWW::Mechanize.

Comment: Javascript has been studied and implemented and it works.  I just wanted to see if I could use Selenium HTMLUNIT to save time for future webpages that have similar but different Javascript implementations.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable JavaScript explicitly when using the HtmlUnit Driver:

```
driver.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
```

According to [http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/HtmlUnitDriver](the docs), it should emulate IE's JavaScript handling by default.

Comment: driver.setJavascriptEnabled(true);  Is this equivalent to 'driver = webdriver.Remote(desired_capabilities=webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.HTMLUNITWITHJS)'

Comment: To add a little more to the discussion... To see if the .page_source produces the desired results I save a file of the browser and driver after executing *scrollBy*.  I compare the files and the browser usually has many more lines (more data) than the driver.  This tells me the driver is not responding to *scrollBy*

Answer (score 0):

When I tried the same method, I got error messages that selenium crashed while connecting `java` to simulate `javascript`.

I wrote the script into execute_script method then the code works well.

I guess the communication between selenium and java server part is not configured properly.

Enabling the `javascript` with `HTMLUNITDRIVERWITHJS` is possible and quick ;)